# Google Maps Distance Calculator api

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I found this cool feature in google map that allows to calculate distance between two points of interest. It doesn't simple calculate the linear distance petween points but allows to draw on the Map the route on the map. Have you ever used it? Do you know where i can find the API documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Google's Maps API is publicly available. You might be looking for [DistanceMatrix](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DistanceMatrixService). You could then use [Polyline](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Polyline) to create the route, and [DrawingManager](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DrawingManager) to draw it.